# Display Random of Integers in array

Tags: java, random, arraylist

How I am going to display random of integers using this code?

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class RandTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int nos[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < nos.length; i++){
           System.out.println(nos[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The result should be "Random"

```
3
5
2
1
6
4
```

What I am getting earlier is "Random"

```
1
2
2
6
1
3
```

Comment: i don't think, you would be getting last one result.

Comment: use the random number generator you instantiated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
Collections.shuffle(integerList);
for (Integer i : integerList) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```